# Trailer Hub Grease Identification Grey/Silver

Tags: grease

I am trying to repack axle bearings for a 6x10 enclosed trailer I just bought before a long trip. When I opened it up I couldn't tell what grease this is. Please advise, I want to reuse the same grease type to avoid any compatibility issues. Axle is Dexter 3500lbs, PN 05-AX106IS 8 but I can't find any details.

The closest I have found is maybe Long-Life Grease + MoS2 but I can't seem to find this in a tube for grease gun and am also not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, but this looks a lot like anti-seize.

Realistically, any high pressure grease will work just fine. To prevent compatibility issues, just clean the bearings and races thoroughly and then use the new grease in its place. Easiest way is to take it all apart and wipe everything clean. When you re-pack the bearings themselves, it'll push all of the old grease out.

Looking closer at the image, it seems there is a grease zerk in the end. You can attempt to just push new grease through to get rid of all the old grease, but taking it apart and cleaning everything is still your best choice if you can do it. If not, clean up what you can and then push clean grease through until that's all you see. No matter what you do, it's going to be a mess. The old grease mixing with the new should not create an issue. Just get rid of as much of it as possible.